# Piwik: Not able to get ALL pages data using API

Tags: php, matomo

I am using following API:

```
http://analytics.example.com/index.php?module=API&method=Actions.getPageUrls&idSite=1&period=day&date=2013-11-12&format=JSON&token_auth=example&filter_limit=-1
```

Previously I was getting only 100 records. After putting filter_limit=-1 now I am getting 500 records. Still the last item returned is Others which shows data for "All other URLs"

Then I referred http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/#faq_54 
And I added all 4 properties in `config/config.ini.php` .. 
Still it is showing me only 500 records for next day analytics data!

Do I need to restart something after adding these 4 properties ? I already tried restarting apache.. Piwik is All PHP code.. so not sure what to restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to instead change /usr/piwik/config/global.ini.php in same directory

```
datatable_archiving_maximum_rows_actions=5000
```

and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do not change in global.ini. Change in config.ini itself. It didnt work because you might have missed to specify the section.

Specify "General" before the config line.

```
[General]
datatable_archiving_maximum_rows_actions=5000
```